# Generated data - check if not data entry exists. to move data viewbag and save database

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

My problem is that as student_UID was generated, I have to check in SQL server database that student_UID has been generated, it has not been received by any student before, if a student has not received it, then he has to allot it to new student. –
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GMbM.jpg)

```
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace SchoolWeb.Controllers
{
    public class StudentController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Registration()
        {
            //Random No Generator
            var random = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
            var StudentUID = SudentUniqueNo(random);

            //Student UID Not Exists Checks
            //var TbleSUID = new tbleStudentUID();

            ViewBag.StudentUID = StudentUID;
            return View();
        }

        private object SudentUniqueNo(RNGCryptoServiceProvider random)
        {
            const int noOfDigits = 16;
            const int maxOddWeight = 7 * 9;
            const int maxEvenWeight = 15 * 9;

            long total = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < noOfDigits; i++)
            {
                int maxWeight;
                if (i % 2 == 0) // even position
                {
                    maxWeight = maxEvenWeight;
                }
                else // odd position
                {
                    maxWeight = maxOddWeight;
                }

                int digit = GenerateRandomDigit(random, maxWeight);
                total = total * 10 + digit;
            }

            return total;
        }

        private int GenerateRandomDigit(RNGCryptoServiceProvider random, int maxWeight)
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4];
            random.GetBytes(buffer);
            int value = BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, 0) & 0x7FFFFFFF; // use only positive numbers
            return value % maxWeight / (maxWeight / 10); // normalize to 0-9
        }

        public IActionResult Enqury()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult Stutas()
        {
            return View();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I have read several times your question tile and I do not understand it. Also, you question lacks a description of your problem. Feel free to check the help section and its "How to ask a question" topic and edit your question.

Comment: My problem is that as student_UID was generated, I have to check in SQL server database that student_UID has been generated, it has not been received by any student before, if a student has not received it, then he has to allot it to new student.

Comment: Why don't you use a GUID at c# code? Or a SQL Server identity column?

Comment: You question is not very clear. Here is a step-by-step guide to working with ORM https://dotnethow.net/a-step-by-step-guide-to-configuring-entity-framework-in-your-net-web-api-project/

Comment: Call your database and see if it exists? Use a guid instead?